# Safely access local static variable from a detached thread

Tags: multithreading, static

I have a function(`say func()`) in which i have a local static variable `A`. Apart from that, i have a detached thread which calls `func()` and accesses `A`. Now, when the `main()` returns , that local static variable `A` gets destroyed but the detached thread is still running as it will be destroyed by C++ Runtime.

What's the best way I can ensure that my detached thread doesn't access destroyed local static variable `A`?

Comment: Re, "What's the best way...?" Don't allow `main()` to return. Hard to say more without knowing why your application creates a detached thread or, what else `main()` does before it returns.

Comment: @besmirched 
1. Not returning from main() is out of question.
2. Detaching thread is a requirement.
3. main() doesn't do any thing special before returning.